# Concatenating date fields with Field Calculator ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I am attempting to calculate a field based on date and time of two other fields.  How should my expression read in ArcPy?  Both fields are date type with the values of the `ORIGDTDATE` reading `11/18/2016` while `ORIGDTTIME` reading `9:52:00 AM`  I would like for my new output for ORIGDTDATE to equal `11/18/2016 9:52:00 AM`

```
import arcpy
calcExpression =  [!ORIGDTDATE!] + [!ORIGDTTIME!]
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "ORIGDTDATE",ORIGDTDATE + !ORIGDTTIME!,"PYTHON_9.3")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
expression =  "!ORIGDTDATE!+\" \"+ !ORIGDTTIME!"
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "ORIGDTDATE",expression,"PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: This syntax is incorrect for the calcExpression and I do not want to calculate it as a TEXT field.

Comment: updated expression

Comment: That is also incorrect.

Comment: Ok, updated again, got this to work on existing date field.